# sorting a javascript array of objects by 2 values

Tags: javascript, typescript, prettier

I have an array of objects, and I want the selected object to always be first. Then, if the object has a `role` === `External` but it's not selected, I want that to always by last. If it doesn't match either, it's just in between the two.

```
const exampleObj = [
  { role: 'other', selected: false },
  { role: 'External', selected: false },
  { role: 'External', selected: false },
  { role: 'other', selected: true },
  { role: 'other', selected: false },
]
```

This works:

```
  exampleObj.sort((a, b) => {
        if (!a.selected && b.selected) return 1
        if (a.selected && !b.selected) return -1
        if (!a.role !== 'External' && b.role !== 'External') return 1
        if (a.role !== 'External' && !b.role !== 'External') return -1
        return 0
```

But I'm getting the prettier error

```
TS2367: This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'boolean' and 'string' have no overlap.
    108 |             if (!a.selected && b.selected) return 1
    109 |             if (a.selected && !b.selected) return -1
  > 110 |             if (!a.role !== 'External' && b.role !== 'External') return 1
        |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    111 |             if (a.role !== 'External' && !b.role !== 'External') return -1
    112 |             return 0
    113 |           })

TS2367: This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'boolean' and 'string' have no overlap.
    109 |             if (a.selected && !b.selected) return -1
    110 |             if (!a.role !== 'External' && b.role !== 'External') return 1
  > 111 |             if (a.role !== 'External' && !b.role !== 'External') return -1
        |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    112 |             return 0
    113 |           })
    114 |         : []
```

But if I remove those 2 lines, it's obviously not going to push the `External` to the end. What am I missing here?

Comment: See [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table). Also `if (!(a !== b))` is more typically written `if (a === b)`.

Comment: `!a.role !== 'External'` becomes `false !== 'External'` or `true !== 'External'` which will always be `true`.

Comment: @jarmod omg that got rid of the error... i feel dumb lol thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `a.role === 'External' && b.role !== 'External'` instead

`!a.role !== 'External'` is same as `false !== 'External'` because  `!a.role` will be evaluated first and the result is compared to the string.

Answer (score 1):

You say `!'string'` which is always false. Because the exclamation mark is casting the variable (value) to boolean and negating it.
So You actually say:

```
false !== 'string'
```

Which is always `true`. that's why it says "This condition will always return 'true'"

Answer (score 1):

The ! before a and b string variables are the problem. `if (!a.role !== 'External' && b.role !== 'External') return 1` evaluates to "if (true !== 'External'.... Remove those ! for `if (a.role !== 'External' && b.role !== 'External') return 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a more concise approach by using deltas of the conditions.

```js
const
    array = [{ role: 'other', selected: false }, { role: 'External', selected: false }, { role: 'External', selected: false }, { role: 'other', selected: true }, { role: 'other', selected: false }];

array.sort((a, b) =>
    b.selected - a.selected ||
    (a.role === 'External' && !a.selected) - (b.role === 'External' && !b.selected)
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```